# Have there been attempts to represent floats with unsigned or signed integers?

Tags: c++, c, math, integer, ieee-754

I wonder if there are studies and attempts in designing a float-like ( IEEE754 ) type, where the decimal part and the integer part are handled by an `int` or an `unsigned int` each, or any other kind of design that can lead to a float-like implemented with integers .

I'm especially curious for a study about general performances, valid range for numerical representation, etc etc ... and anything you can say about this.

Comment: You looking for better precision?

Comment: Certainly this has been done historically.  (Even did a version myself back ca 1970, to handle numbers outside of the range of IBM 7090 float values.)  But IEEE double precision "captures" most of the applications, and the rest are usually handled by some sort of "long decimal" type.

Comment: Take a look at various implementations of Decimal data type for various languages. That could give you quite a lot of interesting information.

Comment: Trying to map IEEE754 ranges of numbers to an `int` type for the integer part isn't possible with a single `int` since the numeric range in the float format is too wide. So it depends upon what your goals are. Are you really talking about doing a fixed point representation? And what range are you looking to represent?

Comment: (You're not going to find anything faster than IEEE, given that virtually all platforms have specialized hardware support for it.)

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey nope, I don't really care about a signed float, and float computation is tipically expensive, I wonder if there is a way to make a float cheaper with a new type based on a less expensive integer or even better, an unsigned integer.

Comment: I programmed c64, which had 32 bit floats, emulated by 8 bit integers.

Comment: @HotLicks see my previous comment, I only care about making cheaper math operations between 2 floats basically.

Comment: Again, due to the hardware support there's nothing "cheaper" than IEEE on most platforms.  (In some cases float multiplication/division is actually faster than integer.)  If you did need similar support on a micro lacking IEEE then it would make sense to do something like what you describe.

Comment: @HotLicks well, yes and no, tipically a float operation requires more cycles than an operation based on integers. Also I would like to deal with unsigned integers for all my types.

Comment: @user3485710 sometimes slower than 1 operation, but you are not implementing a floating point with integers and doing 1 operation in integers per floating point operation.  If your only goal is speed, and you are not on some obscure hardware, your quest is misguided.

Comment: Typically a float divide will be as fast or faster than an integer divide.  Multiply the integer may have an edge, but it depends on the specific hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) numbers or [decimal floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) ? There's even an implementation of them in [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed_002dPoint.html) . See also [these](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/) resources about decimal arithmetic.

Comment: yes, I think so, after digging a little I think that the right "keyword" is that one, it also looks like there will be a new life for this kind of approach since there is a proposal for the next C++1y standard for fixed point math.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it was , especially in old technology where there was no floating point unit in CPU. In some cases where you know the values exactly you can use this approach to gain some speed on those platforms. However this is uncommon now and this practice died a long time ago. 
I've seen it used mostly in games where performance is critical. 
This kind of tricks fall into a strange kind of optimization practice, the kind where you write your own sqrt , or your own float->int conversion functions.

Comment: and it died because programmers are lazy or because of a particular reason ?

Comment: @user2485710 no , it's because hardware got a lot better and you can't beat the hardware there.

Comment: can you name a couple of platforms so I can have a chance to get docs about those platforms and their floating point representation ?

Comment: @user2485710 I can't tell for certain ,i haven't lived that era, i think first gameboy has no floating point unit. In any case you should look for technology that is at least 15+ years old

Comment: It's still very common on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

[I asked this on comp.arch some time ago and got some really good answers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/mashey%2420jthill/comp.arch/JmLV5AaF3Nc/Cf2UyFikauwJ), leading off with this from Dr. Mashey:

> |> I have wondered whether using all that FP space for another three or
>   |> four integer units and supplying hand-tuned FP libs for each model would
>   |> pay for itself, but I've always figured that if that could be made to
>   |> pay, the designers would have done it.  Perhaps now that superscalar is
>   |> the order of the day, it'll be done soon.
>
> 1) FP hardware is there, because if you care about FP performance at
>   all, it is very difficult to emulate the required behavior with typical
>   integer operations at a reasonable speed.  These days, typical
>   FP add/mul are ~2-3 clocks latency, with 1-cycle repeat rates.
>
> 2) There is, of course, substantial experience in the microprocessor
>   world of people supplying libraries to do FP withotu an FP unit,
>   for systems where FP use was expected to be infrequent, or where
>   the FP coprocessor wasn't yet available.  This has been true for
>   X86s, 68KS, and MIPS, among others.  In MIPS' case:
>           (a) There were systems with R2000s by themselves.
>           (b) Then there was a big coprocessor board.
>           (c) Finally, the R2010 FPU came out, and fairly rapidly, most
>           systems had both R2000 & R2010.  In the embedded markets, there
>           are many uses for CPUs without FPUs still.
>
> 3) Put another way: to any competitors: it is really a cool idea to
>   drop the hardware FP and emulate via integer ops :-)

Comment: as a comment to this post, I should also say that the hardware support for the FPU in the ARM world is a quite recent discovery, especially if we consider the whole pair hardware+kernel .

Answer (score 1):

One example of the things you're asking about is "fixed point" arithmetic. If you notice that in a positional system it doesn't matter that much where the decimal point is, as long as you keep proper track of it, you can decide to keep the point in a specific place. This is an example of what I'm trying to say, in base 10:
  123 + 456 = 579
  1.23 + 4.56 = 5.79

Well, you can do the same in base 2. Decide where your point should be and do the operations. Back in the 8088 and IBM PS/2 8086 days I had my assembly language and C++ students graph a simple Mandelbrot set in this way. Horrible precision if you limit yourself to the size of the CPU registers but much faster than the emulated floating point libraries.

This site seems to have more detailed information: http://x86asm.net/articles/fixed-point-arithmetic-and-tricks/